# Powershell to select Directory location into variable using System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the directory location using the GUI **System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog**

This is the script I have so far:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
$fileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$fileDialog.ShowDialog()
Write-Host "Directory selected is $($fileDialog.DirectoryName)"
```

There is no error but the result is always empty?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>     Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
    $fileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $fileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $fileDialog.CheckPathExists
    Write-Host "Directory selected is $($fileDialog.DirectoryName)"
Cancel
True
Directory selected is
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `FileName` property. You can use [Split-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7) or [similar means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=netframework-4.8) to safely get the directory name from a file path. Also, make sure to check that the dialog wasn't cancelled:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
$fileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$fileDialog.CheckPathExists = $true
if ($fileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $directoryName = Split-Path $fileDialog.FileName
    Write-Host "Directory selected is $directoryName"
}
```

Alternatively (or better, even), you can use a [folder browser dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog?view=netframework-4.8):

```
$dialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
if ($dialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $directoryName = $dialog.SelectedPath
    Write-Host "Directory selected is $directoryName"
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, yes it works great.
May I know what is the command to clear up the memory after the application has been completed or the file has been saved succesfully?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Can you explain what exactly you mean "clear the memory"? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: what I mean is the garbage collector or something to out into the Try/Catch,Finally { } section to release the memory?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer No need to do anything here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and `DirectoryName` is not a property within $fileDialog.
The following properties are available:

[image]

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'
$fileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$fileDialog.ShowDialog()
$Dir = Split-Path $fileDialog.FileName
Write-Host "Directory selected is $Dir"
```

[image: Result]

Comment: somehow it is giving me the error like below when selecting the directory:
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length"
At line:4 char:1
+ $Dir = $fileDialog.FileName.Substring(0, $fileDialog.FileName.lastInd ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Which powershell version are you using? I tested this with 5.1

Comment: Yes, 5.1 it is executed from Powershell ISE in Windows Server 2016

Comment: can you try and run it from a normal powershell console window? ISE is known for running the code differently then normal powerhell windows. (I recommend using VSCode for writing powershell code)

Comment: Do not rely on diy string manipulation, there are built-in methods for safely working with paths.

Comment: replaced the substring part for split-path. More easy to read and works like a charm

Comment: @PetertheAutomator, many thanks to you, Peter for your sharing and the suggestion.